# Why is "error empty response' after fetch request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, fs

My project is bundled on webpack. I've a form which post data to other local server, where saving in txt file. All is okay, data saves correctly, but after a few minutes, on client returns alert "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" and then the same form values save to file second time. Why is it saves twice? How to fix this problem.

My fetch post request:

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/post", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(fragment),
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
})
  .then(console.log(fragment))
  .catch(alert);
```

My server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello')
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors({
    allowedOrigins: [
        'http://localhost:9000'
    ]
}));

app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('post')
})

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    res = 0;
    if (req.body.film.includes('день: Понеділок')) {
        fs.appendFile('booking.monday.txt',
            `${req.body.name},${req.body.number},${req.body.film}\n`,
            function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Saved!');
            });
    }
})
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation (and remove unnecessary or add missing code).

Comment: What is your intention with `if (err) { throw err }` in the `fetch` options?

Comment: you're not sending a response back like you are on the `.get` callback

Comment: Andreas, I need this form alert error, no?

Comment: Dragos, may you explain, how to send a response? I don't need any data on client from server. What should I do?

Comment: @AlexKhanas after the `fs.appendFile...` line just add `res.send('ok')` or a similar message to tell the client it's been successfully saved.